# PHP arrays and using of arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with all week days in it `array("mon"=>"monday" …)`.  I want to take week day on certain condition : for example, if it is monday, take item from the array and echo it. Here is some code to illustrate :

```
$d = date("D");

if ($d == "Mon") {
    echo "Today is Monday";
} elseif ($d == "Tue") {
    echo "Today is Tuesday";
} elseif ($d == "Wed") {
    echo "Today is Wednesday";
} elseif ($d == "Thu") {
    echo "Today is Thursday";
} elseif ($d == "Fri") {
    echo "Today is Friday";
} elseif ($d == "Sat") {
    echo "Today is Saturday";
} else {
    echo "Today is sunday";
}
```

I have tried this one but it is too much of code, I want to have it smaller code and shorter! How can I proceed?

Comment: You don't even need an array, simply `echo 'Today is ', date("l");`

Comment: If you really want to use an array, then `$days = array('Sunday', 'Monday',..etc);
echo 'Today is ', $days[date("w")];`

Comment: Well, thats a long way of doing it...

Comment: Thank you i want to use array cos i want to echo my native language encoding

Answer (score 1):

You could try to directly get the day from the array like this:

```
$d = date("D");
$dayArray = array(
                  "Mon" => "Monday",
                  "Tue" => "Tuesday",
                  "Wed" => "Wednesday",
                  "Thu" => "Thursday",
                  "Fri" => "Friday",
                  "Sat" => "Saturday",
                  "Sun" => "Sunday"
                  );
if (empty($dayArray[$d])) {
    echo "I don't recognize " . $d . ".";
} else {
    echo $dayArray[$d];
}
```